# Is there an equivalent to jQuery's .data() method in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, custom-data-attribute

Suppose I write a quiz like this in HTML using the data attribute:

```
<p>The cow ran in front of the <input data-answer="car"></input>.</p>
<p>Then the <input data-answer="man"></input> hit the breaks.</p>
```

How do I access the data-answer attribute in AngularJS? I know how to do it in jQuery using the .data method. Is there an equivalent in AngularJS? Am I doing this all wrong? Should I just use jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

In AngularJS you rarely have to manipulate DOM elements directly; usually you only manipulate data.

In this case, you need a Controller which holds the data, and HTML to display it. For example:

```js
function AnswerController($scope){
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        //do something with $scope.man and $scope.car
    }
}
```

```html
<p>The cow ran in front of the <input ng-model="car" /><p>
<p>Then the <input ng-model="man" /> the breaks.</p>
```

You could also use `<input ng-model="answers.man" />` to get 1 resulting object containing all answers.

Be sure to try the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to get familiar with the basic concepts of Angular. The most important rule (which you really have to repeat to yourself when you are starting out) is: nearly never use jQuery. If you *have* to use jQuery (you rarely do) then *never* use it from a controller, but always from a directive.

The 'JavaScript Projects' example on the [AngularJS home page](http://angularjs.org/#project-html) is also very helpful.

Comment: I see how the separation of data from markup may be a disadvantage for this particular application. If the quiz were a list of multiple choice questions (uniformly formatted) the separation would be a great advantage, especially with the ng-repeat function. The format of this particular quiz has data closely linked with fields in sentences. Thus every field needs to be linked by hand which adds an extra step.

Comment: The separation itself is never (IMHO) a disadvantage. It always (when used correctly) leads to cleaner, better understandable code. A more important question would be: is the application big enough (development time and/or lines of code) to invest time in a (for you) new framework?

Comment: I have concluded that for this project AngularJS is overkill. The proposed system is not really a web app, but a document with some extra behavioral functionality. In that way I think the jQuery paradigm fits quite well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a directive, inside the directive you'll have a `link` function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    console.log(attrs.answer); //manipulate as you need
}
```

Angular also comes with jqLite, be sure to check that out before implementing the entire jQ lib.

Comment: tymeJV, if you will pardon my js noobness, how then would I access the contents of the input field? Would I use ng-model? Seems like if I used ng-model then I would need to have a separate variable in the scope for every quiz question - not good.

Comment: Yes you would use `ng-model` to access the value, probably something like `ng-model='quiz.question1'`, so then you have `$scope.quiz` which is an object of all the questions.